# Column (field) name in Sybase::CTLib (Perl) after nsql query

Tags: perl, sybase

I am migrating a Perl script which interacts with Sybase from DBLIB DB Interface to CTLIB.
Both DBLIB and CTLIB support nsql method.

In DBLib I can get the column name like this using the nsql -

```
$qry = 'Select * from A';
@data = $dbh->nsql($qry,{});
$string = $dbh->dbcolname($colid)
```

How can i get the column name in CTLib by using the nsql?

```
$qry = 'Select * from A';
@data = $dbh->nsql($qry,"ARRAY");
#Replacement of dbcolname?
```

There's a way to get the column names if i request a hash instead of an ARRAY from nsql. They keys of the Hash are column names. But I want to get the field names only with ARRAY call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native way to do it in CTlib. The only solution is to rewrite your own version of NSQL. which can be forked from the source of CTLib.

Answer (score 0):

For **DBI** it is:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "Prepare exception: $DBI::errstr";
$rv  = $sth->execute() or die "Execute exception: $DBI::errstr";
$res = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();                    

# Array reference with cols captions, which were retrived
$names = $sth->{NAME};          

# Array reference with types of cols, which were retrived         
$types = $sth->{TYPE};                               
$sth->finish();
```

---

For **Sybase::CTlib** try >>

`@names = $dbh->ct_col_names`

Retrieve the column names of the current query. If the current query is not a select statement, then an empty array is returned.

`@types = $dbh->ct_col_types([$doAssoc])`

Retrieve the column types of the currently executing query. If $doAssoc is non-0, then a hash (aka associative array) is returned with column names/column type pairs.

---

`@dat = $dbh->dbnextrow([$doAssoc [, $wantRef]])`

Retrieve one row. dbnextrow() returns an array of scalars, one for each column value. If $doAssoc is non-0, then dbnextrow() returns a hash (aka associative array) with **column name**/value pairs. This relieves the programmer from having to call dbbind() or dbdata().

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works for DBI. But I cant use DBI due to Project constraints. I am looking for a CTLib solution.

Comment: Just tried it. But these methods doesn't work with nsql. They work fine with ct_execute and ct_results.

Comment: I have actually tried using them before as well, Thats why posted the question mentioning nsql specifically.

Comment: @MohitJain - You wrote in the first comment above that you are looking for CTLib solution, so that's it. Why you **have** to use **nsql**?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a CTLib solution but with nsql call. I am migrating the code from DBLib to CTLib. and i cant change much things. nsql method is used in the previous DBLib version. The same method is available with CTLib. But ct_col_types doesn't work. I am looking for a work around.